# This password reset token is invalid - using laravel

Tags: laravel, passwords, token, change-password

I am having issue on reset password i am using auth routes and view of laravel and i have run php artisan make:auth and its generated built in routes and views but i dont know where is the issue:

```
           public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}


            public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

i dont know where is the issue? 
your help will be highly appreciated?[image]

I have also attached the screen shot and this is built in cold provided by laravel i did not write any code.

Comment: The problem is, because your token in table password_reset is already expired (expiration can be set up in `/config/auth.php`. This has nothing to do with form token (`_token`) as @Shokry Mohamed mentioned

Answer (score -1):

Add This Tag To Head

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: i am still confused why this error is appearing , can you please further guide me